# Joomla - SMTP server error: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: php, forms, smtp, joomla2.5

I cannot make this thing work. One one of the sub-domain we have joomla website configured sending feedback form emails using PHP.

But this website on other domain is configured sending email using SMTP. On submitting the form we see the message

"The following from address failed: jawad.ahmad@mydomain.com

SMTP server error: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender "

Please help.